# What should we do when questions are tagged with ui2012

Tags: discussion, tags

We have several questions tagged with [ui2012](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui2012) [AmbientDataContext is not properly initialised](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/221/ambientdatacontext-is-not-properly-initialised), [Extending Tridion Experience Manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/214/extending-the-tridion-experience-manager-ui2012) and [Tridion Experience Manager & Static Implementation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/270/tridion-ui-2012-static-implementation)

One of these was also tagged with [experience-manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-manager) and i've retagged the other two to also include that tag.

My question is should we leave or remove the [ui2012](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui2012) tag from those questions. To me it seems redundant but Bart retaged one of the questions and left the ui2012 tag on it so I'm wondering if people thing we should also allow that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should just create a synonym which maps it appropriately. Unfortunately we need 1250 rep to suggest a synonym, so only Bart and Nuno can do that right now.

Answer (score 3):

I already started suggesting a few tag synonyms, like [xpm](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xpm) as a synonym for [experience-manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-manager), and those are awaiting votes, but we need you guys to get a higher reputation indeed.

The weird thing with [ui2012](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui2012) is that it is seen as a version specific tag, and that I cannot suggest as a synonym apparently. Its telling me only a moderator (so a real one I guess) can do that.

I didn't report that yet as an issue, figured it wasn't going to change much for now and isn't that urgent. When we have our own appointed moderators we could ask one of them to change it into a synonym for [experience-manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-manager). If you all disagree and would like it taken care of we can flag this post as a feature.

What we could already do is make sure we retag those questions with [experience-manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-manager) and change the use of UI2012 for Experience Manager in the text.

Comment: I've made suggested edits to the 4 questions affected to change the use of UI2012 for Experience Manager and remove the ui2012 tag from them.